# How to use a specific directory Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI (android)

Tags: android, url, media-player, uri

I want to use the music files that are in a specific folder I created on the sdcard to do a playlist. 
But I dont know how to replace the `Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`
by my repertory URL in

```
audioCursor = this.managedQuery(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

of the `MediaStore.audio.

Do you think this is possible?
If yes, how?
thank you!

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this.

Comment: Does anyone know answer to this question?